# Add numerical content of UITextFields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel

I have four separate UITextFields and I want to add the numerical value of them all and then display the content within a UILabel, below is current code:

```
- (void)updateString {

    self.string1 = textField1.text;
    self.string2 = textField2.text;
    self.string3 = textField3.text;
    self.string4 = textField4.text;
    self.string5 = textField5.text;        

    label.text = self.total; // total is an NSString and label is a UILabel

}
```

I am unable to add together the numerical values within each textField1/2/3... and store the value within total and then update the label. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't you be converting to an int or NSNumber at some point??

Comment: Well that's where I get stuck, where/what would suggest doing?

Answer (score 3):

NSString has a method on it `-intValue`.  That is what you want to use.

Check the section "Getting Numeric Values" in the [NSString documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
int totalValue = [textField1.text intValue] + [textField2.text intValue]...;

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The total value is %d", totalValue];
```